# Div on click expands but does not contract on clicking again

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I click on my div it expands, but when i click again it does not contact. Clicking on the Div again should close/contract it back.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<div style="height:35px;" onclick="style='height:auto'">
  <p style="color: #9DA4AB;font-size: 15px;">{{list.TASKDESC}}</p>
</div>
```

> Please note i am using IONIC and i am looking at a simplest way to achieve this.

Comment: The problem is, that onclick you are just setting the height to auto - you would need a way to toggle the height

Comment: can you guide appropriate way, some code will help, like how to contract

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this,

in your html,

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let qa of groups; let i=index" text-wrap (click)="toggleGroup(i)" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(i)}">

        //header
        <ion-card-header style="white-space: normal;">
            {{qa.id}}. {{qa.question}}
            <ion-icon style="position:absolute !important;right: 20px;" color="success" item-right [name]="isGroupShown(i) ? 'arrow-dropdown' : 'arrow-dropright'"></ion-icon>
        </ion-card-header>

        //content
        <ion-card-content *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">
            {{qa.answer|removehtmltag}}
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

in your ts,

```
export class ClassName{

shownGroup = null;

 constructor(){}
 toggleGroup(group) {
       if (this.isGroupShown(group)) {
           this.shownGroup = null;
       } else {
           this.shownGroup = group;
       }
   };   

   isGroupShown(group) {
       return this.shownGroup === group;
   };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution with Pure css and HTML
HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="post" />
<label for="post">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.Libero fuga facilis vel consectetur quos sapiente deleniti eveniet dolores tempore eos deserunt officia quis ab? Excepturi vero tempore minus beatae voluptatem!</div>
</label>

<p>The text above expends when you click on it. (checkbox and label used to achieve)</p>
```

CSS

```
input {
  display: none;
}
div {
  max-height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input:checked ~ label div {
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}
```

[Demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVwway?editors=1100)

Comment: if i hard code text in html, all works but i call data in ionic like this, it doesnt work `<input type="checkbox" id="post" />
<label for="post">
<div class="dd">
  <p style="color: #9DA4AB;font-size: 15px;">{{list.TASKDESC}}</p>
</div>
</label>`